# Reinterpreting Unicode strings

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I'm receiving unicode data from a client, stored in a dictionary called "data". The following code

```
variable1 = '\u03b5\u0061\u0073\u0064\u0066'
print("TYPE1 = " + str(type(variable1)))
print("VAR1 = " + variable1)

variable2 = data['text']
print("TYPE2 = " + str(type(variable2)))
print("VAR2 = " + variable2)
```

prints

```
TYPE1 = <class 'str'>
VAR1 = εasdf
TYPE2 = <class 'str'>
VAR2 = \u03b5\u0061\u0073\u0064\u0066
```

This suggests that the data from the client is somehow not interpreted properly. Writing the variables to file also gives the exact same result: the file has the literal "\u03b5\u0061\u0073\u0064\u0066". How can I "reinterpret" that unicode string so that I get the same result as the inline variable?

The following did NOT work:

- `eval(variable2)` (Error: "unexpected character after line
  continuation character")

With `print(variable2.encode().decode())`, I get `VAR2 = Îµ`.

By using `.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape')`, I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)`

In the shell:

```
>>> "\u03b5\u0061\u0073\u0064\u0066"
'εasdf'
```

Comment: What about `u'\u03b5\u0061\u0073\u0064\u0066'`?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how consistently the input data got corrupted (or encoded in some particular way), but for the given example the following should work:

```
>>> data = '\\u03b5\\u0061\\u0073\\u0064\\u0066'
>>> print(data)
\u03b5\u0061\u0073\u0064\u0066
>>> text = data.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape')
>>> print(text)
εasdf
```

The "unicode_escape" codec is provided exactly for Python-style Unicode escapes. It also works with escapes of the form `\xNN` and `\U000NNNNN`, mixed with literal ASCII characters.

A few things to note:

- The `.encode('ascii')` step is necessary, because `.decode` only exists for `bytes`, not `str`.
- If you have a mixture of non-ASCII literals and Unicode escapes (as is allowed in Python `str` literals), you can try `encode('utf-8')`, but I haven't thought this through.
- `eval` doesn't work here because there are no quotes around the data.
- It's possible that your data originates from JSON, where the `\uNNNN` escapes also exist (but not the `\xNN` and `\U000NNNNN` ones). If this is the case, you have to deal separately with characters above U+FFFF (eg. emojis), which are represented by surrogate pairs.

Comment: Updated my question with your suggestions and the results.

Comment: The data does indeed originate from JSON.

Comment: Have you tried `.encode('utf-8')` instead of ASCII? Maybe you could also update your example to reproduce the `UnicodeEncodeError` as well.

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce it without the client sending it (that would have made it a lot simpler). In the Python shell, printing these literals gives the right output. I guess `str = "Îµ"` is the closest thing: if you can make that into an `ε` then I guess it would work.

Comment: It would seem that `"Îµ"` indeed is what is actually received.

Comment: "Îμ" looks like an issue with the terminal configuration. If Python sends the bytes for "ε", but your terminal interpretes them as Latin-1 (or Windows CP-1252), it will print mojibake "Îμ".

Comment: ... but if you get the original JSON data, you can just `import json; json.loads(data)` if data is a string, or `json.load(stream)` if it is a filehandle.

Comment: I use `json.loads(data)` where `data` is the raw data before attempting to use it.

Comment: Got it working, thanks for the tips which got me in the right direction (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the unicode (JavaScript example below)

```
function escapeUnicode(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^\0-~]/g, function(ch) {
        return "\\u" + ("000" + ch.charCodeAt().toString(16)).slice(-4);
    });
}
```

before sending the data and using

`input.encode("utf-8").decode('unicode-escape')`

seemed to work.